v4l2loopback-dkms getting past secure boot
Sorry in advance as I am almost positive this is not possible but I have been asked to confirm as I have not had any luck on my own. I am trying to install v4l2loopback-dkms without having to configure secure boot. The issue arises from the fact that this needs to be done through scripts as well as done remotely so I cannot access the BIOS. I have tried using the dkms method listed on the github but the key is rejected. I looked through the Secure Boot on the wiki of the github but that doesn't work since I can't access the BIOS. I know this is an odd situation but using v4l2loopback-dkms is needed for a new functionality that also needs to work for existing devices where configuring secure boot was not necessary for any previous features. Any help or just a confirmation that this is not possible would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Secure Boot intentionally provides no way to reconfigure, bypass, or disable it unless you're physically present during the boot process.
